# Proof for property of the cardinality of the right coset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> $\left | Hg \right |=\left | H \right |$

My lecture notes provides the proof as follows but I am left none the wiser. A more verbose proof would be appreciated.

The proof given is as:

Define

$ \varphi :H\rightarrow Hg$

$hx \mapsto hg$ is a bijection

Since

$h_{1}g=h_{2}g
\Rightarrow h_{1}=h_{2}$

And the proof concludes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

We define the function $\varphi:H\to Hg$ by $\varphi(h)=hg$ for each $h\in H$. This is clearly a surjection, so in order to show that it’s a bijection, we need only show that it’s injective. Suppose that $\varphi(h_1)=\varphi(h_2)$; then $h_1g=h_2g$, and multiplying on the right by $g^{-1}$ yields the desired $h_1=h_2$. Thus, $\varphi$ is injective and hence a bijection, and $|Hg|=|H|$.